# Is it enough to disable a toolbar button if the OS does not support the underlying functionality

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

Is it enough to disable a toolbar button if the OS does not support the underlying functionality such as the new Twitter Support in iOS 5 or do I have to remove it entirely from its toolbar?

Comment: You determine the "look and feel".  Depends on how badly you want to confuse your users.  If it were me I'd at least blank the button text and make it look somehow less "buttonish".

Comment: @HotLicks Ok you'v got me convinced. I'm going to remove it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is slightly subjective in that this is more of a design/user experience issue than anything else. I believe Apple may approve such an app, but you'll have to ask yourself this:

If you were a user and you saw a button that was never enabled. Would you fully understand why?

I would remove the button entirely for unsupported features - else it's like dangling a steak in front of a lion behind bars. Having a perpetually disabled buttons may confuse your users or cause them to be angry that they can't get this feature without upgrading or changing their device (in the case of differences between iPhone and iPod touch for example).

Comment: Or if it's a setting issue, say Safari is restricted, you grey it out and when they tap it explain why it's greyed out.

Comment: @Jasarien That's a valid remark and I'm probably going to remove the button. I was just curious if such a button would prevent appstore approval of an app.